# Angular formating yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm datetime string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime

I am struggling with some datetime formating in angularJS.

I would like to obtain the following date format `25/11/1990 14:35`
based on a datetime `string` containing `"1990-11-25 14:35:00"` without having to create a `Date` object in the controller.

It seems like angular can only achieve proper datetime formatting if the input is a `Date` object or if the `String` does not contain hours or minutes

index.html

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
   String: {{'1990-11-25 14:35:00' | date:"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"}}<br>
   string date: {{'1990-11-25' | date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}<br>
   Date: {{myDate | date:"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"}}
</div>
```

controller.js

```
function Ctrl($scope)
{
    $scope.myDate = new Date("1990-11-25 14:35:00");
}
```

Output

```
string: 1990-11-25 14:35:00 
string date: 25/11/1990 
date: 25/11/1990 14:35
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CkBWL/612/

According to [angular's documentation on the date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), 
the only format allowed for datetime string are:

> datetime string formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ

Is there so a way to format a string containing `"1990-11-25 14:35:00"` into `25/11/1990 14:35` directly in the html without having to create a `Date` object ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Whats wrong with a Date object?

Comment: I would like to avoid any controller data treatment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems like angular can only achieve proper datetime formatting if the input is a Date object or if the String does not contain hours or minutes

If you want your string recognized as a date you should use the date formatted according to the [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. So `1990-11-25 14:35:00` becomes `1990-11-25T14:35:00Z`, you can also include the offset if you want (its in the spec). You can then use the existing [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) built into Angular.

From the [date filter documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) on param `date`

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various **ISO 8601 datetime string formats** (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the local timezone.

#### Code update

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    String: {{'1990-11-25T14:35:00Z' | date:"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"}}
    <br>
    Date: {{date | date:"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"}}
</div>

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.date = "1990-11-25T14:35:00Z";
}
```

[Updated JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CkBWL/613/)

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid any data treatment but it seems like the only way to do so. The input date format (yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM) I'm using is forced by MySQL `datetime` formatting unfortunately...

Comment: @PierreRoudaut - you could also create your custom date filter that converts your string to an ISO date time and then chains it to the angular date filter. Basically a call through after you format it correctly (or convert it to javascript date). That would then still isolate the code away from the controller.

Comment: That's actually a great idea !